# Save all radio communication to file

Tags: cellular-radio

I have a rooted phone. So, your phone has a radio right? It does calls, uses network, et cetera. Can you access the radio with root permissions?

How could I log all raw radio communication to a file?

Comment: You cannot access modem. It's completely isolated from the Android OS. The communication between Android and modem is through Radio Interface Layer (`rild`) which is closed source, specific to OEM. You may however check `logcat -b radio` to see what's already being logged. Or reverse engineer the RIL daemon.

Comment: On a rooted device you may be able to use Xposed and hook all calls to the RIL for logging them. But this would have an significant impact on your device speed. Some functions may even fail because due to Xposed and the hook taking too much time.